# In CodeIgniter how to pass data between loaded views

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let say we are loading two or more views in the same class method like so:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('body');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

and you decide to create a variable inside the **head** view (**$cat_name**) like this example:

```
<?php
foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
    $selected = FALSE;
    if ($this->router->class == 'category' && $this->router->method == 'id' && $this->uri->segment(3) == $value->id) {
        $cat_name = $value->name;
        $selected = TRUE;
    }
 ?>
    <option value="<?= $value->id; ?>" <?= ($selected ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?= $value->name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

This needed a loop to get that variable.

I want to pass that variable (**$cat_name**) to the next view without redoing the loop, that is just a waste.

**what I am trying to achieve is minimizing the number of loops.**

Comment: Why are you looping it inside the view? Do it in controller and send to the view.

Comment: Do it in the controller, and then pass it to the **views*. Problem solved!

Comment: ya but this loop is generating html that is why this loop is in the view

Comment: Added a solution for that. Try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of loading all of that in controller load it in your view
create new file, let say template

```
 $this->load->view('template',$variable);
```

and in your template

```
//do the loop here

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('body');
$this->load->view('footer')
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create model for generating selects if You want to save MVC in Your project. I know, that's looks strange, but it will help You many times after

**Controller**

```
// load model
$this->load->model('myselect_model');
// get array with marked element
$select_data = $this->myselect_model->setSelected($categories, $this->router->class, $this->router->method, $this->uri->segment(3));
// get filled html
$my_html_select = $this->load->view('select_tpl',array('select'=>$select_data),TRUE);
// use it at any controller
$this->load->vars(array('my_select'=>$my_html_select));

// some views
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('body');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

**Model 'myselect_model'**

```
function setSelected($items, $uri_controller,$uri_method, $uri_value){
       // createing temp array for our list
       $tmp = array();
       foreach($items as $key=>$value){
             // appending item
             $tmp['options'][$key] = $value;
             if ($uri_controller == 'category' && $uri_method == 'id' && $uri_value == $value->id) 
             {
                   // saving selected for any reason to use after
                   $tmp['selected'] = array('name'=>$value->name, 'id'=>$value->id);
                   // marking this item as selected
                   $tmp['options'][$key]['selected'] = TRUE;
             }
       }
       // returning completed array
       return $tmp;
}
```

**View 'select_tpl'**

```
<?php if(!empty($select)){?>
     <select>
     <?php foreach($select['options'] as $option){?>
             <option value="<?=$option->id?>"<?=(isset($option['selected']) && $option['selected']==TRUE ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "")?>><?=$option->name?></option>
     <?php }
     </select>
<?php } ?>
```

**views/header**

```
<body><?=$my_select?><i>template here</i>
```

**views/body**

```
<p>some html here and our select goes here-> <?=$my_select?></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try like this:

Create a model like so:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Custom_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function printSelect(){
        // Do some logic and looping here
        $html = "<select><option>...</option></select>";
        return $html
    }
}
```

Then call that model from your views like so..

$this->custom_model->printSelect();

Remember to load the model first.
$this->load->model('path/to/your/model/folder/custom_model');

This way, every time you want to print your  you can simply call that method from your view.

I hope this helps.